# Why is my PNG icon fuzzy when I reduce its size in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I downloaded an icon in `png` format. Now I try to resize it to 20x20 pixels using Photoshop CS5. This causes it to become fuzzy, as shown in Photoshop's navigator. I want to use the smaller image for a website. How can I make the reduced image have the same quality as the original I downloaded?

Here is  a screenshot of the photoshop screen.
[image: youtube logo of size 20x20]

Comment: Try to resize it with Ctrl+T and move left-right-up-down a bit to have more sharp edges. Sub-pixel anti-aliasing is causing blurry edges.

Comment: it is not just blurry edges , the whole picture showing in navigator section (at the top right of the screen) at 100% is blurry. Is it natural?

Comment: Please share a screenshot.

Comment: yes please share the png icon, i think maybe the final size is to small for the image content …

Comment: i'm downloading it from iconfinder.net , it is a youtube logo icon of 128x128. I'm just trying to make it 20x20, and in the navigator of photoshop the icon showing is fuzzy

Comment: I added a screenshot , please take a look

Comment: The text / details are just way too small. Either use a different image with simpler details, or use a bigger image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't trust the Navigator panel, trust your export.

The Navigator panel is just a tool to visually orient yourself in large works at big zooms. It is not meant as a preview of what you're going to see when you export a file.

In your case, the Navigator preview is way larger than the file's actual size. Therefore, Photoshop makes a pixelated, fuzzy preview.

Try and export your file (`File > Save for Web...`), and check that. It's bound to be crisp.

Comment: Just to make this clear for the OP. The `100%` in Navigator panel is the document zoom level. The Navigator panel thumbnail fits itself to whatever size the panel is.

Answer (score -1):

How i thought it is just too small for the logo to get sharp edges anymore, i would suggest using a icon font such as [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/youtube/) for this small icons!

EDIT:

here is a example of what i mean:

[image] 
*128x128 px*

[image] 
*20x20 px*